# How to isolate a high proportion of available helminth ova from animal faeces/feces without damaging them?

Tags: lab-techniques, parasitology, centrifugation

I need to isolate large numbers (tens to hundreds of thousands) of cat (and later dog) hookworm ova from cat/dog faeces.

I have a centrifuge, and various sieves with pore sizes of 20, 63, 75, 106, 125, and 180 microns as well as the ability to create various flotation solutions to any specific gravity

The specific gravity of the ova is 1.21 and they are oblong, their size is 50 by 38 microns varying by ±5 microns.

I have tried sieving the cat faeces after emulsifying them using a liquidiser. I pass them through successively smaller pore size sieves but the concentrated ova still contains a very large admixture of unwanted faecal material.

Flotation following sieving by bracketing the ova in successive flotations of iron sulphate results in too much contamination and many ova are lost.

My technique is self-taught and clearly lacking.

I need to remove 98-99% of the unwanted faecal material without damaging the ova, which are not very resilient.

My access to equipment any more sophisticated than that listed is unlikely but if costing less than a thousand pounds possible.

I am new to this area, so I am sorry if I have omitted anything required or failed to follow form and protocol.

Thank you very much in advance.